# How to display response body into html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I want to display the var maplink as a href in my html. I already input the values in and the result is the maplink which I want to display. I created the maplink method in the remoteMethod. The maplink is displayed in my console, how do I get it to display in the html? I want to display it in my find-location.html
[console.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCi1w.png)

geocode.js

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('FindLocationController', ['$scope', '$state', 'GeoCode', function ($scope, $state, GeoCode) {
    $scope.GeoCodes = [];

    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        GeoCode
          .geocode({
              address: $scope.geoCode.address,
              zipCode: $scope.geoCode.zipCode,
              city: $scope.geoCode.city,                  
          })
          .$promise
          .then(function () {
              $state.go('find-location');
          });
    };
}])
```

geo-code.js

```
    var maplink = "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lng;
    console.log('maplink is ' + maplink);
    // make a callback function cb
    cb(null, maplink);
```

remoteMethod()

```
      [GeoCode.remoteMethod(
    'geocode', {
      http: {
        path: '/geocode',
        verb: 'post'
      },
      accepts: \[{
        arg: 'address',
        type: 'string',
        required: true
      }, {
        arg: 'city',
        type: 'string',
        required: true
      }, {
        arg: 'zipCode',
        type: 'string',
        required: true
      }\],
      returns: {
        arg: 'maplink',
        type: 'string',
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: can you provide [mcve]?

Comment: possibly better use: [ng-map](https://ngmap.github.io/)?

Answer (score 0):

Select body using angular.element method and append maplink to it. Check below code.

```
var maplink = "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lng;
console.log('maplink is ' + maplink);
// Append maplink to body
var body = angular.element( document.querySelector( 'body' ) );
body.append(maplink);
// make a callback function cb
cb(null, maplink);
```

Comment: Will it retrieve the particular result from the console to display it as a function to open another tab? (google api result)